# Complex subquery in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity called `Insurance` like this:

```
public class Insurance : BaseEntity, IExpirationDocument
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string PathToCertificate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name => InsuranceType.Name;
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int InsuranceTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual InsuranceType InsuranceType { get; set; }
    public int InsurerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Insurer Insurer { get; set; }
    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
    public int? DocumentEmailHistoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentEmailHistory DocumentEmailHistory { get; set; }

    public Insurance()
    {
        Active = true;
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to do this type of query with Entity Framework:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Insurances i1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         insuranceTypeId, applicantid, MAX(IssueDate) as 'maxissuedate'
     FROM 
         Insurances
     GROUP BY 
         insuranceTypeId, applicantid) AS i2 ON i1.applicantid = i2.applicantid
                                             AND i1.insuranceTypeId = i2.insuranceTypeId
WHERE 
    i1.issueDate = i2.maxissuedate
```

Comment: Can there be only one `Insurance` according to each `InsuranceTypeId`, `ApplicantId` and `Max(IssueDate)`?

Comment: yes, that is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get *latest issued* `Insurance` according to `InsuranceTypeId` and `ApplicantId` you can group data according to needed properties, order by `IssueDate` descendingly and take only one `Insurance` info. Of course it will not give you the same *query* but it will give you the same *result*:

```
var result = context.Insurances
    .GroupBy(m => new { m.InsuranceTypeId , m.ApplicantId  })
    .Select( g => new
    {
        MaxInsurance = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.IssueDate)
            .Take(1)        
    })
    .SelectMany(m => m.MaxInsurance);
```